# Does the <location> tag in web.config override settings on the tag level or on the attribute level?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

In particular, if my web.config looks like this:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="20480" />
  ...
</system.web>
```

and I want to increase the execution timeout of a particular page **while keeping the other `httpRuntime` options as above**, does it suffice to write

```
<location path="Statistics.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

or do I need to write

```
<location path="Statistics.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="20480" executionTimeout="180" />
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I have [read the documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815174/how-to-make-application-and-directory-specific-configuration-settings), but, unfortunately, it does not address this particular point. I know that the latter option would be the most "safe", but I try to stick to the "dont't repeat yourself" principle as much as possible.